# Auto filter in searchbox in Rails App

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, search

I've a City model and there is 81 cities in this model, only db field is name.

I want the user to be able to select a city from a dropdown in the navbar, but also the user should be able to filter these cities quickly by typing a few letters at the beginning. The exact example that I want to do is in this site: www.dabble.co

I dont know which way should I follow to do this. Any idea is wellcome.

Comment: You will need to use AJAX to do something like that. Rails options_from_collection_for_select method for a select box will give you the first letter though. That may be enough for just 81 cities.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JQuery there is http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/, which has an example for the country select bar.
You want to make a collection of your cities accessible in the controller, which renders your form.
E.g.

```
def new
  @cities = City.all
end
```

You can easily add the corresponding `<select>` form tag with the following helper:

```
<%= select_tag("cities",
           options_from_collection_for_select(@cities, 'id', 'name'),
           id: "selectize_cities" # sets the id of the select tag 
)%>
```

Depending on your Javascript+Rails setup, after requiring the **all** components of selectize.js you can add to your javascript file

```
$("#selectize_cities").selectize();
```

If you want to **manually** implement this (without jQuery), one way could be to pass the data into a div tag in the html view and access it with Javascript

```
<%= div.tag(id: "selfmade", data_cities: @cities.to_json)%> #tag helper
const cities = JSON.parse(document.querySelector("#lol").getAttribute('data_cities')); //plain js
```

There is also a Railscasts on youtube "simple search form" which should help you move further!